# Automate video call android

Tags: java, android, adb, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to automate a video call over android, I succeed by making a regular call from device1 to device2 by `am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:device2.number` 
after device2 answers I'm starting a video call by UI, The problem with this function that the UI changes every few days so I need to change function every few days. is there a better way starting a video code from the cmd or trough an application with boradcast reciver?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give me the solution? how did you? I tried following site.  https://github.com/nubomedia-vtt/nubo-test  and github question is  https://github.com/nubomedia-vtt/kurento-room-client-android/issues/3  can you please guide me to do that stuff